# Как сделать ограничение записей в Firebase RealTime?

Tags: база-данных, firebase, realtime

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать **правило** в RealTime Database в Firebase чтобы 1 авторизированный пользователь мог делать не больше 10 записей в бд за 1 минуту?